# Importing the code changes while comparing the code from source control

Tags: tfs

Can I import the changes b/w the local version and the checkin version of the code.I am using TFS 2010.The reason I am asking this question is that ,I want send my code to an external reviewer who will not have access to TFS source control .

My current thinking is that  if can I some import the changes then reviewer can review the changes through windiff or beyond compare tool.

Comment: To clarify: You want to handover code to an external reviewer and only want to import the changed code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just:

- Get latest
- Copy it to a directory called `<<filename>>-new.cs`
- Get specific version
- Copy it to the same directory call it `<<filename>>-old.cs`
- Send both files to the reviewer and have him use windiff (or whatever) to review?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to import only the changed code, you can first check out all the files, then copy the files the reviewer send to you over the local files.

Then use the tfpt uu command from the TFS Power Tools to undo all unchanged files. Now you only have the list of files that are modified.

Answer (score 0):

For a (very) different approach you could use git with TFS and push updates to your reviewers remote repository using git.  You can then just pull their changes when you're ready and push them to TFS when you've looked at them.

For an idea on how this might be done have a look at http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/04/git-tfs-working-together-version-2.html

Comment: Richard, that looks very convoluted and non integrated...Why is this approch better than Ewalds?

Comment: If you're using git at the remote end you get to see all the changes they made (i.e. checkin history).  Just doing a tfpt uu will only give you the result of smashing together two different code bases.  It works fine and I do it myself often enough, I was just providing an option for using a DVCS since this is a classic DVCS scenario